# How can I loop through indexes that rely on multiple functions?

Tags: javascript

I am using two types of elements, `.element` and `.summary`. The index of both classes correspond to each other, so when a user has a `mouseover` event on `.element`, a class should be added to its corresponding `.summary`. Similarly, that same class should be removed on `mouseout`.

In other words, I'm looking to have the `.styling` class only applied to `.summary` when `.element` is on mouseover

Without declaring so many variables, I was wondering the most efficient way to loop through these elements.

```js
var abc = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
var xyz = document.getElementsByClassName("summary");

for (let i = 1; i < xyz.length; i++) {
  abc[i].addEventListener("mouseover", movein(i), false);
  abc[i].addEventListener("mouseout", moveout(i), false);
}

function movein(i) {
  xyz[i].classList.add("styling");
}

function moveout(i) {
  xyz[i].classList.remove("styling");
}
```

```css
.element {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.styling {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Element 1</div>
<div class="element">Element 2</div>
<div class="element">Element 3</div>

<div class="summary">Summary 1</div>
<div class="summary">Summary 2</div>
<div class="summary">Summary 3</div>
```

From what I can tell, these functions run but it doesn't work on `mouseover`.

Comment: Your code looks quite reasonable ATM, though you're invoking the handlers immediately instead of creating a function to pass as a listener

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Is there a generally accepted way of doing that?

Comment: Just pass the function instead of invoking it?

Comment: instead of `movein(i)`, try `()=>{movein(i);}` . Also your loop starts with `1` instead of `0`, which could cause some unexpected behavior

Comment: @lastr2d2 that worked flawlessly. Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: ;) then consider check the answers below for other solutions. and maybe accept the one that help you the most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to loop, in fact it's probably best you don't. If you have containers for each section of your HTML: elements, and summaries, it's much more efficient to use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch element events as they bubble up the DOM, and use one handler to decide how to style your summaries depending on their data attributes.

```js
// Cache the containers
const elements = document.querySelector('#elements');
const summaries = document.querySelector('#summaries');

// Add listeners to the containers
elements.addEventListener('mouseover', handleMouse, false);
elements.addEventListener('mouseout', handleMouse, false);

function handleMouse(e) {

  // Destructure the type and id from the element
  const { type, target: { dataset: { id } } } = e;

  // Find the corresponding summary - this uses
  // a template literal to create the query
  const summary = summaries.querySelector(`[data-id="${id}"]`);

  // And then, depending on the event type, add or remove the style
  if (type === 'mouseover') {
    summary.classList.add("styling");
  } else {
    summary.classList.remove("styling");
  }
}
```

```css
.element { cursor: pointer; }
.styling { background: red; }
```

```html
<div id="elements">
  <div data-id="1" class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div data-id="2" class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div data-id="3" class="element">Element 3</div>
</div>

<div id="summaries">
  <div data-id="1" class="summary">Summary 1</div>
  <div data-id="2" class="summary">Summary 2</div>
  <div data-id="3" class="summary">Summary 3</div>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, and not have to update your html. We programmatically set up an attribute so we can get it's index when we mouse over it. Then we use that index to find the associated summary. **Note** that you don't pass the `i` through the event listener - you test for the `event.target` and pick up that shiny new attribute with `event.target.dataset` per the code below.

Another bonus here is that we've combined the event listener logic which you can see makes sense. This answer leverages your existing structure, uses less code and is easy to understand.

```js
var abc = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
var xyz = document.getElementsByClassName("summary");
for (let i = 0; i < xyz.length; i++) {
  abc[i].setAttribute('data-index', i)
  abc[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mousemove);
  abc[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mousemove);

}

function mousemove(event) {
  let element = xyz[event.target.dataset.index];
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') element.classList.add("styling");
  else element.classList.remove("styling");
}
```

```css
.element {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.styling {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Element 1</div>
<div class="element">Element 2</div>
<div class="element">Element 3</div>

<div class="summary">Summary 1</div>
<div class="summary">Summary 2</div>
<div class="summary">Summary 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I apologize that I should have clarified. I'm looking to have the `.styling` class only applied to `.summary` when `.element` is on mouseover.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing your code to just refer to the functions (not call them) in addEventListener, to loop starting at 0 (not 1), and to use ids to get the corresponding elements...

There's nothing wrong with a short loop.

```js
var abc = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
var xyz = document.getElementsByClassName("summary");

// fixed, was i=1
for (let i = 0; i < xyz.length; i++) {
  // fixed, was movein(i), moveout(i)
  abc[i].addEventListener("mouseover", movein, false);
  abc[i].addEventListener("mouseout", moveout, false);
}

// these get events as params, and can use the event.target.id
// to distinguish which element was triggered
function movein(event) {
  let id = event.target.id
  xyz[id].classList.add("styling");
}

function moveout(event) {
  let id = event.target.id
  xyz[id].classList.remove("styling");
}
```

```css
.element {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.styling {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" id="0">Element 1</div>
<div class="element" id="1">Element 2</div>
<div class="element" id="2">Element 3</div>

<div class="summary">Summary 1</div>
<div class="summary">Summary 2</div>
<div class="summary">Summary 3</div>
```